# Communication between EJBs deployed in different Application Servers from different vendors

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I ‘m trying to create a small EJB 3.1 application in which I want to use two application servers from two different vendors. (JBoss 6.1.0 Final and Glassfish 3.1). This is just to experience the taste of distributed applications and new features of EJB3.1.

This is the problem I’m having…

I have created a simple EJB (kind of a hello world ejb) and deployed it in GlassFish server which is running in the machine A. Let’s call it GlassFishHelloWorldEjb. This one has business remote and local views. 
I have created another EJB project in which I have an EJB called JBossHelloWorldEjb. I have deployed it in the Jboss server which is running in the machine B.

Now I want to inject GlassFishHelloWorldEjb to a reference in the JBossHelloWorldEjb so that I can call it within the JBossHelloWorldEjb. Then I have a web app deployed in the Jboss which calls the JBossHelloWorldEjb.

MyWebApp(Jboss, machine B)-----> JBossHelloWorldEjb (Jboss, machine B)----> GlassFishHelloWorldEjb(GlassFish, Machine A)

I tried many ways to inject the GlassFishHelloWorldEjb in to the JBossHelloWorldEjb but failed. Could some please shed some light to achieve this.

Would greatly appreciate if you could show me the way to do this through both INJECTION and Programmatic JNDI look up.

Cheers 
Lekamge

Comment: I didn't know people still used distributed EJBs - even though they were designed with that in mind ;)

Comment: @HoundDog and what do they use instead?

Comment: @Piotr Nowicki I think the trend is to use SOAP Web Services (which then wrap the EJB). It's easier, and client agnostic.

Comment: Oh, so by "distributed EJBs" you meant: remote views of EJBs?

Comment: @Piotr Nowicki Distributed, as in not in the same place (2 different app servers in this case).

Answer (score 1):

one option might be to use  Spring RemoteEJB Proxies
OR. import client required jars for remote and write your own wrapper